# if statement does not work - script doesn't stop when skillpoints are below 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have if statement that doesn't work.

I want the script to stop working when the skillpoints are 0 or below.

My code:

```
var skillpoints = 5;

        if (skillpoints > 0) {

            // Dodawanie skillpointów
        
            $('.str .stat-plus img').click(function() {
                var val = $('.str-img div').text();
                var new_val = parseInt($('.str-img div').text(),10) + 1 ;
                $('.str-img div').text(new_val);
                $('.str input').val(new_val);
                skillpoints--;
                $('.skillpoints').text(skillpoints);
                $('.register-skillpoints').val(skillpoints);
            });
    }
```

Comment: This feels like the logic got switched around or an XY problem; why would you conditionally bind event listeners as such? What’re you trying to do? The code is not evaluated magically just because `skillpoints` is updated: unless you’re not showing us the entirety of your code. See how to share a [mcve].

Comment: I am totally confused about the upvotes on this question on WHY but well !!! can you share a reproducible example or minimal working example of your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the if condition into your click handler, like this:

```js
$('.str .stat-plus img').click(function() {
  if (skillpoints > 0) {
    // etc
  }
}
```

Otherwise, the if condition is checked only once at page load, and never again when clicking.